# CSS3: Do we still need to use browser prefixes?

Tags: css

Do we still need to use the browser prefixes for css3 properties, for example `-moz-box-shadow`, `-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;`  etc?

Comment: If you want to support browsers that only supported properties with those prefixes then yes. If not, no.

Comment: Is someone going to have to repeat this question every few months?

Comment: I don't see the point of using invalid CSS just to support some odd feature. The prefixed versions are really meant for testing. I do not use any form of prefixed property because these effects are not important at all to the display of content, and *shouldn't* be. These are bonus effects, so it shouldn't matter if the browser supports them or not. If they do, great. If they don't, the site is still perfectly viewable. If that statement isn't true, you did something wrong.

Comment: @animuson - some of us want our site to look its best in as many browsers as possible.  That means using prefixed properties in some cases.  You can go up on your high horse if you want, but you're just throwing away features from many browsers if you want to do that - your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important thing to take into consideration is that if you are using Vendor Prefixes, then you are clearly using an experimental feature - not only will this property not work in older versions of the browsers you're targeting, and should thus not be used for anything essential, but they are also subject to change. You really shouldn't use experimental features in a production environment.

To answer your question, if you want to target a browser that only supports a vendor-prefixed version of the CSS property, then yes, you do need to do that. However, if you include a non-vendor-prefixed version of it as well, then all browsers will support that declaration eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Found the [entry](http://jitendravyas.com/css/save-time-and-keep-css-valid-by-using-prefix-free-javascript-library-for-vendor-prefixes/) on someone's blog here on SO and I think it's useful. You can use Javascript to make it compatible for all browsers without writing CSS properties for every single browser

Comment: But how does this answer the question?

Comment: He's asking whether to use browser prefixes or not. He has many answers that say "yes" so I gave him a way to use a single property but stays browser compatible. Feel free to delete the answer, if it does not belong here.

Answer (score 1):

For now, yes. Some properties are not supported by all browsers or in different ways since not all properties are set in the standard.

[Css3 info](http://www.css3.info/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes (at this moment). Since modern browsers do not support the same set of CSS3 effects yet, prefixes are still needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to support the latest browsers, then no.  Many companies are still using older versions of Firefox or IE, however.  So by dropping the extensions you won't have those features, even if the browser supports them.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing is to make sure you use the 'proper' CSS3 rule after the other rules, in this way the browser will use this rule if and when it becomes available. e.g.:

```
webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
-moz-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
```